# Lua in JS runtime (Fengari): String representation of large integers has trailing ".0"

Tags: javascript, lua

So I have a slightly complex problem. To help with the overall issue, here's the background:

I'm converting an app to javascript, with part of the app using lua to interpret templates. I don't control these templates. However, the template parser is in lua, and it looks at the template string for lines beginning with `%` or lines that contain `<% … %>` tags. For example:

```
this is output as is
% for index, value in ipairs{1,2,3} do -- this is lua code that doesn't output
index:<% index %>; value:<% value %>
% end
```

would output:

```
this is output as is
index:1; value:1
index:2; value:2
index:3; value:3
```

lines that don't start with `%` get wrapped in a lua helper `append(line_contents)` function, and if they have tags, such as `foo<% tag_variable %>bar` it gets transformed like `append('foo'..(tag_variable)..'bar')`. Lines that start with `%` get transformed to lua code (essentially eval'd).
This code works well, and I can control the logic that parses the template, and modify the `append` helper. (But not the template code)

So the main issue happens when the template code is working with ~10-digit numbers (integers). In C-lua the string representation of those is just the integer part when the value is used in a template tag. However, in the [Fengari runtime](https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari) of Lua in JS, the string representation of some of those numbers sometimes has a trailing `.0`. This means output varies between the runtimes. I'm trying to figure out ways to fix this.

<del>I believe that this is caused because Fengari relies on the JS `Number.prototype.toString` function to format numbers as strings when needed. And it looks like this is an oddity of that function,</del> that some point some 10+ digit numbers start having trailing decimal 0s. *This is defined behavior for lua, not javascript, and happens when the internal representation uses a float type, as Egor mentions in the comments*. I've googled around and can't find any mention of this problem exactly, but believe it's related to the float representation of numbers. I could use `Number.prototype.toFixed`, but that doesn't fix the problem globally. I also want to understand better why this is happening, as well as try to find a solution. I am considering somehow overwriting `Number.prototype.toString` if that would work universally, but I know that would be tricky, if it is even possible... Additionally, I could change how the template tags are wrapped and add a formatting helper around the output, and that might fix the issue in some cases, but it doesn't help cases where numbers are getting concatenated by template code... So how might I approach this?

Reference: here's the spec on how numbers are represented as strings in JS: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type. But I'm apparently too tired to understand that dense math definition today :).

Comment: Fengari implements Lua 5.3 with `int32` integers and `double` FP numbers.  10-digit numbers don't fit into `int32`, so they are `double`.  When Lua 5.3 converts `double` to string, it ALWAYS puts decimal point.  To avoid this behavior, do not rely on standard Lua `tostring()` and do not concatenate a number with a string.  Instead convert numbers with `string.format("%.0f", x)`.

Comment: You can redefine `tostring()`, but you can not change the concatenation logic.

Comment: `I am considering somehow overwriting Number.prototype.toString` - this would not help.

Comment: BTW, `int32` in Fengari could wraparound in calculation (eg: `65536*65536==0`), while you're expecting the usual numeric (`double`) behavior as in JS.  IMO, the correct way to get compatibility with JS is to avoid integers in Fengari, example: do not write `x=123`, instead write `x=123.0`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff all good things to know, and very helpful. But they don't lend to a solution just yet, unfortunately. But if I'm understanding correctly, this is not specifically JS, except that Fengari uses int32 instead of the larger C standard (int64 on modern machines?). So fixing it on the JS side doesn't work, because it's not a JS problem, and not using the same `toString` algorithm as JS... (Which for some reason I didn't check, but really should have :) )

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is there anyway to modify how Lua/Fengari prints numbers without modifying the source?

Comment: You can ask by creating an issue on github.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I was considering that. Still looking for more answers though :).

Comment: @wp78de That only works by finding every place code is being concatenated and modifying the code there. If I could do that, it would work though. Can't. Also, why the `gsub`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on the Fengari GitHub page here: https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari/issues/183

> fengari's behaviour intentionally matches Lua 5.3 here. See `LUA_COMPAT_FLOATSTRING` and https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.c.html#luaO_tostring
> and the matching fengari code:
>
> `fengari/src/lobject.js` (Lines 592 to 594 in 0c9631c)

```js
 if (!LUA_COMPAT_FLOATSTRING && /^[-0123456789]+$/.test(str)) {  /* looks like an int? */ 
     str += '.0'; /* adds '.0' to result: lua_getlocaledecpoint removed as optimisation */ 
 }
```

> This is documented here:
>
> `fengari/src/luaconf.js` (Lines 123 to 129 in 0c9631c)

```js
 /* 
 @@ LUA_COMPAT_FLOATSTRING makes Lua format integral floats without a 
 @@ a float mark ('.0'). 
 ** This macro is not on by default even in compatibility mode, 
 ** because this is not really an incompatibility. 
 */ 
 const LUA_COMPAT_FLOATSTRING = conf.LUA_COMPAT_FLOATSTRING || false;
```

This can be changed by setting `process.env.FENGARICONF` with a `JSON` string defining `LUA_COMPAT_FLOATSTRING`